# How to append an an array but not the memory location?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, nested-lists

I am generating a large set of monte carlo data and ideally want to store in it an array of arrays.

When i use the `array.append(x)` and then cycle over a loop that returns a new array for x when I look at the elements of the array at the end they are all the same as the last array `x` added to the list. I believe this must be because i'm adding the memory location to the list and not the actual array data hence when I add more arrays all the other elements that point to the same location also update.

Is there anyway to prevent this by setting a kwarg or something or do i have to construct my arrays in a different way?

```
#test to illustrate point 
import numpy as np
x = np.random.choice((-1, 1), size=(5, 5))
array_test = []
for T in range(10):
    array_test.append(x)
    print(x)
    x += 10
print(array_test)
```

Comment: You need to make a copy of x each time you append

Comment: `array_test.append(x.copy())`, as Jerfov2 suggested

Comment: Thanks a lot it now works as intended! Is this an efficient way of doing it or might it be better doing it an alternative way?

Comment: The key is that as written, you are appending the same `x` object in each loop.  It instead you appended `x.copy()`, or somehow used a fresh `x` each loop (a new `random.choice`) you wouldn't have this problem.  `x+=10` mutates `x`; `x = x+10` does not.